# Jenkins pass variable out of script section

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm trying to create a pipeline that creates EC2 instances and I want to execute some shell commands on it.

After the Terraform applies the plan, AWS create new instances:

1. Build [no info about public IP yet]
2. Staging [no info about public IP yet]

It's impossible to retrieve public ipv4 information at the plan stage, therefore I created that construction:

```
stage ('Running command on a Build server') {
            steps {
                script {
                    BUILD_INSTANCE_IP = sh (
                        script: """
                        aws --region eu-central-1 ec2 describe-instances --filter \
                        "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --query \
                        "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PublicIpAddress, Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value|[0]]" \
                        --output text | grep Build | cut -f1 //retrieve 'Build' instance IP
                        """, returnStdout: true
                        ).trim()
                        sleep time: 3, unit: 'MINUTES' // wait 3 minutes until instance will be available to connect
                        sh ( script: """ssh -i ${AWS_KEY} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ubuntu@${BUILD_INSTANCE_IP} touch /home/ubuntu/test.txt""", returnStdout: true ).trim()
```

So, here I need to connect to the instance via sshagent {} directive, but after Jenkins moves to a new section, the data of variable 1 is reset to zero.

How do I make a variable that won't change?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this example will help you, How to use or re-use a variable across the stage throughout the pipeline

```
def x
node() {
    stage('shell') {
        x = sh(script: "echo 10", returnStdout: true) as int // needed to convert from String to int
        print x // result = 10
    }
    stage('groovy') {
        x = x + 10
        print x // result = 20
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work with the SSH connection I wrote about earlier. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried to executed my example ? and its not working with agent connect with ssh you mean ?

Comment: I tried to mix your example with my needs and finally it worked as follows:
def x
node() {
  stage ('shell') {
   sh("""ssh root@${env.x} cat /etc/os-release""")
  }
}
In all other cases, the contents of the variable x were empty. Thanks for the help though!